# Starting pythonWin in QGIS directory?

Tags: qgis, installation, pythonwin

I have python installed here:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin
```

When I click on pythonWIn I get this error:
The application cannot locate win32.ui.pyd (or Python) 126. The specified module could not be found. I got python 2.7.5 when I downloaded and installed QGIS 2.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first glance it seems like you need to set the python path variable to your specific folder.

- Did you check if your machine has a python path variable?
- Did you try to reinstall pythonWin.?
- Did any other IDLE work?

For a detailed look see this question: [Adding python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7#6318188).
Short summing up:

1. Right click on "My computer"
2. Click "Properties"
3. Click "Advanced system settings" in the side panel
4. Click "Environment Variables"
5. Check if the variable  pythonpath is set  and if not, add it with your path as argument

If this does not solve the problem try do the steps 1 to 4 and append the path of python  to the Path variable, as described in the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318188/3659824)

If I missed the point please let me know so I cant adjust my answer.

Comment: Added python path with directory argument from above. Same reult. Tried adding it to path variable. Same result. Do I need to reinstall python? If so do I need to put in QGIS 2.18\apps ?

Comment: do you have another python installation beside the one from qgis? I would not recommend installing it in the qgis folder because of the dependencies qgis has.

Comment: Should i uninstall it from QGIS or can I have it installed in two different locations?

Comment: I reinstalled python without uninstalling it from the QGIS directory in program files. I then downloaded and installed pythonwin. Works fine now although I'm curious to see what will happen when i run QGIS scripts. Thanks LaughU